# Uncaught type error in my javascript form

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to make a form that fills out a task, if there is no input when adding the task an alert is sent reading please fill the task, if not then i want the console to read success
when I try this code I get a type error

Thanks for any help to anyone who decides to find what I am doing wrong so I can know in the future, kudos

JAVASCRIPT:

```
window.addEventListener('load', () => {
    const form = document.querySelector("#new-task-form");
    const input = document.querySelector("new-task-input");
    const list_el = document.querySelector("#tasks");

    form.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();

        const task = input.value;
        
        if (!task) {
            alert("Please fill out the task");
        } else {
            console.log("Success");
        }
    })
})
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Task List 2023</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
    <script src="main.js"></script> 
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <h1>Task List 2023</h1>
        <form id="new-task-form">
            <input
                type="text"
                id="new-task-input"
                placeholder="What do you have planned?" />
            <input
                type="submit"
                id="new-task-submit"
                value="Add Task" />
        </form>
    </header>

    <main>
        <section class="task-list">
            <h2>Tasks</h2>
            <div id="tasks">

                <!-- <div class="task">
                    <div class="content">
                        <input 
                            type="text"
                            class="text"
                            value="My shiny task"
                            readonly
                        />
                    </div>
                    <div class="actions">
                        <button class="edit">Edit</button>
                        <button class="delete">Delete</button>
                    </div>
                </div> -->

            </div>
        </section>


    </main>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
:root {
    --dark: #374151;
    --darker: #1F2937;
    --darkest: #111827;
    --gray: #6B7280;
    --light: #EEE;
    --pink: #EC4899;
    --purple: #8B5Cf6;
}

* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    font-family: 'Fire sans', sans-serif
}

body {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    min-height: 100vh;
    background: var(--dark);
    color: #FFF;
}

header {
    padding: 2rem 1rem;
    max-width: 800px;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

header h1 {
    font-size: 2.5rem;
    font-weight: 300;
    color: var(--gray);
    margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

#new-task-form {
    display: flex;
}

input, button {
    appearance: none;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    background: none;
}

#new-task-input {
    flex: 1 1 0%;
    background-color: var(--darker);
    padding: 1rem;
    border-radius: 1rem;
    margin-right: 1rem;
    color: var(--light);
    font-size: 1.25rem;
}

#new-task-input::placeholder {
    color: var(--gray);
}

#new-task-submit {
    color: var(--pink);
    font-size: 1.25rem;
    font-weight: 700;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to right, var(--pink),
    var(--purple));
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: 0.4s;
}

#new-task-submit::hover {
    opacity: 0.8;
}

#new-task-submit::active {
    opacity: 0.6;
}

main {
    flex: 1 1 0%;
    padding: 2rem 1rem;
    max-width: 800px;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.task-list {
    padding: 1rem;

}

.task-list h2 {
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    font-weight: 300;
    color: var(--gray);
    margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

#tasks .task{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    background-color: var(--darkest);
    padding: 1rem;
    border-radius: 1rem;
    margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

#tasks .task .content .text {
    color: var(--light);
    font-size: 1.125rem;
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    transition: 0.4s;
}



#tasks .task .content .text:not(:read-only) {
    color: var(--pink)
}

#tasks .task .actions {
    display: flex;
    margin: 0 -0.5rem;
}

.task .actions button {
    cursor: pointer;
    margin: 0 0.5rem;
    font-size: 1.125rem;
    font-weight: 700;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    transition: 0.4s;
}

.task .actions button:hover {
    opacity: 0.8;
}

.task .actions button:active {
    opacity: 0.6;
}

.task .actions .edit {
    background-image: linear-gradient(to right, var(--pink),
    var(--purple));
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}

.task .actions .delete {
    color: crimson;
}
```

ERROR:

```
main.js:5 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'value')
    at main.js:5:24
(anonymous) @ main.js:5
load (async)
(anonymous) @ main.js:1
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason why you are getting this error

> TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'value')

is because you are trying to read a property specifically `value` from an object that is currently `null`. From what you provided in the javascript code, there is only 1 place that you are trying to access property `value` from an object. It is

```
const task = input.value;
```

If this is the case, it means that your `input` object is currently `null` according to the above reason. To find the root cause of why the `input` is `null`, I tracked back to where it is declared and initialized, which is this line

```
const input = document.querySelector("new-task-input");
```

This is where the `input` is declared and initialized to some value. It is presumably expected to be this input just from looking at your HTML code.

```
<input type="text" id="new-task-input" placeholder="What do you have planned?" />
```

To use `document.querySelector` to select an element by its `id` property, you need to specify by prepending the id with a `#` just like what you already did for the other variables here.

```
const form = document.querySelector("#new-task-form");
const input = document.querySelector("new-task-input");
const list_el = document.querySelector("#tasks");
```

As you can see, `form` and `list_el` do have `#` in front of the id, whereas `input` does not. Therefore, it will not find the element, which results to a `null`.

To fix this, you just need to put `#` in front the value there. So that it will find the element.

To fix it in your code, change the code from

```
const input = document.querySelector("new-task-input");
```

to

```
const input = document.querySelector("#new-task-input");
```

Comment: Wait can you explain in more detail I am still confused D:

Comment: @Gibbli Does the answer fix your problem?

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding what to do

Comment: @Gibbli I have updated the answer with more details. See if this clarifies what you confused. If this answer is helpful, it is customary to upvote such answer. Also, if it solves your issue, please consider accepting such answer.

Comment: Thanks so much, this helped tremendously, this answers my question